# Python multiprocessing: Functions called using pool cannot access global variables declared inside if '__name__' == '__main__' bock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to access a `global variable` declared inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` block from a function which is called by object of class `Pool` for `multiprocessing` purpose.

But it throws `NameError`.

But if I place same variables outside the block the code works just fine.

Demo:

1. When declared outside `if __name__ == '__main__'` block

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

foo = 'OKAY'

def f(x):
    print(foo)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)

    p.map(f, [1, 2])
```

Output:

```
OKAY
OKAY
```

2. When declared inside `if __name__ == '__main__'`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print(foo)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = 'OKAY'
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(f, [1, 2])
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: I do not get an error for the second piece of code given, have you given it to us correctly?

Comment: @Blonded yes sir the code is correct

Comment: Is this all the code you have? For both blocks?

Comment: @Blonded yes sir this is all.

Comment: The `__name__` block is not used when the module is imported.  It's only used when used as script, when `__main__` condition is satisfied.

Comment: @hpaulj I know that.  Both the code snippets in question are runned independently and not imported.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @hpaulj yes sir.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows.  Multiprocessing under WIndows has some distinct features.  This line might be the most relevant: `This allows the newly spawned Python interpreter to safely import the module and then run the module’s foo() function.`

Comment: The error only occurs in combination with multi-processing and only under Windows. So it might be related to the "forking" in Windows and thread-safety.

Comment: Your behavior, plus the line I quoted, imply that under Windows, the subprocesses import the module, and thus `f(x)` does not 'see' any values set by the `main` block.  The documentation states that Windows does not have `os.fork`, so the spawning mechanism is different.